# Is there a bug in @types/d3-selection or is it me?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, typescript-typings

I am working with d3 and typescript and I am confused about the type that is returned from various methods of a Selection.

This is the current [selection interface signature](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d172d3e076f25c468c0177896d9369f23c45259c/types/d3-selection/index.d.ts):

```
/**
 * A D3 Selection of elements.
 *
 * The first generic "GElement" refers to the type of the selected element(s).
 * The second generic "Datum" refers to the type of the datum of a selected element(s).
 * The third generic "PElement" refers to the type of the parent element(s) in the D3 selection.
 * The fourth generic "PDatum" refers to the type of the datum of the parent element(s).
 */
export interface Selection<GElement extends BaseType, Datum, PElement extends BaseType, PDatum> {
```

now this interface has several functions defined that return sub-selections of this selection and most of them return the wrong type, only two are correct in my understanding. Let me show two examples

selectAll (correct)

```
selectAll<DescElement extends BaseType, OldDatum>(selector: string)
: Selection<DescElement, OldDatum, GElement, Datum>;
```

select (incorrect)

```
select<DescElement extends BaseType>(selector: string)
: Selection<DescElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>;
```

So instead of passing its own type into the sub-select's type, the function seems to pass in its parent's type und datum.

This is a complete list of the affected functions (overloads are the same)

```
select         //incorrect
selectAll
selectChild    //incorrect
selectChildren
append         //incorrect
insert         //incorrect
```

I am confused if I didn't understand the concept since the d3 types are downloaded a million times weekly. So I am not sure how to proceed here, and if/where to fix this. Should I open a PR against DefinitelyTyped, or is someone else managing those types?

Comment: I opened a discussion at DefenetlyTyped: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/65932

Comment: Can you post your code and the typescript error you get?